# How can I access the base class variable in javascript from json function

Tags: javascript

My code is work Like [https://jsfiddle.net/89vpLxxy](https://jsfiddle.net/89vpLxxy/)


I have create two function inside the function one is normal function and another one is json function, I can access the base class variable from the normal function but not from json function. How can I access the variable?

I have tried shown below

```
<script>
var funvar=function(A)
{
    alert(A);
    this.name = "Merbin Joe";

    this.fun1=function()
    {
     alert(this.name);
    },

    this.colanfun= {
        saveScore:function ()  {
            alert("HHHHHH : "+this.name);
        }
    }

}

var Obj = new funvar(); 
Obj.fun1();
Obj.colanfun.saveScore(); 
</script>
```

Comment: i guess you want to access the this.name right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your JSON function, this keyword refers to colafun instead of your outer function scope (i.e funvar). You can store the reference of this in a variable self and you can access it.

```
var funvar=function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.name = "Merbin Joe";

    this.fun1=function()
    {
     alert(this.name);
    },

    this.colanfun= {        
        saveScore:function ()  {
            alert("HHHHHH : "+self.name); //Here How Can I access
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'JSON function', but this is what you want:

You need to bind the function to `this` [See bind doc from Mozilla DN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
var funvar=function()
{
    this.name = "Merbin Joe";

    this.fun1=function()
    {
     alert(this.name);
    },

    this.colanfun= {        
        saveScore:function ()  {
            alert("HHHHHH : "+this.name); //Here How Can I access
        }.bind(this)
    }
}


var Obj = new funvar(); 
Obj.fun1();
Obj.colanfun.saveScore();
```

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/89vpLxxy/1/

Comment: May I know the meaning of bind(this)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var funvar=function(A)
{
    var that = this;
    alert(A);
    that.name = "Merbin Joe";

    that.fun1=function()
    {
     alert(that.name);
    },

    that.colanfun= {
        saveScore:function ()  {
            alert("HHHHHH : "+that.name);
        }
    }

}

var Obj = new funvar(); 
Obj.fun1();
Obj.colanfun.saveScore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your function with closure such as this code:

```
this.colanfun= {        
    saveScore:(function(parent) { return function ()  {
        alert("HHHHHH : "+parent.name); //Here How Can I access
    }; }(this))
}
```